# Synonym to poor-rich pair

Tags: word-request, synonyms, antonyms

I am looking for a pair of antonymous words with meaning similar to poor-rich, but slightly different:

- Word A (the synonym of poor) should mean "a person who has exactly enough for surviving, but not more".
- Word B (the synonym of rich) should mean "a person who has more than enough for surviving".

Also, the words A and B should be a matching pair.

Looking at [thethesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/poor), I found the word "meager" which looks like a good candidate for word A. However, I am not sure what its counterpart should be for word B.

Comment: Do you need strictly single words or will phrases work? I'm not sure that there's a single word (for each) that will mean what you want them to.

Comment: I need single words. But the meaning can be approximate.

Comment: Well, the counterpart to "meager", is "ample"... You might consider looking at that definition to see if it does what you're looking for. For example, someone with a "meager" salary, would be barely getting by but a person with an ample salary would have sufficient money to live on. They may not be well-off, but they aren't struggling, either.

Comment: I looked at a dictionary but didn't quite understand if "meager" and "ample" can be adjectives for a person?

Comment: Not in the way that you mean. You would have to say "meager income" or "ample income". There's no relation between either word and wealth, only amount.

Comment: "Meagre" only really works if you use it in conjunction with a word like "salary". "He earns a meagre salary". But then "well-off" is an adjective that describes a personal characteristic, so you couldn't use it in the same way. "He is well-off". (You **couldn't** say "He earns a well-off salary".) In short, I can't find "a pair" of words for you.

Comment: These aren't single words, but you could let A = _Lower middle class_ and B = _Upper middle class_. I don't know of any adjective pair that fits this bill – perhaps *surviving* and *well-off*?

Comment: I don't believe single words with the sense you want are in use in English. You'll have to coin your own: for instance, the common terms  *subsistence income* and *disposable income* suggest the participials *subsistent* and *disponent*. But whatever you come up with you'll have to explain before you use it.

Comment: "above/below the [***poverty line/level***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/poverty-line)" is often used in the US in economic discussions. However words meaning your A and B examples can't be antonyms since it is not over and under, but over and equal.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question specifically, here are some words that mean a person who is poor and some that mean a person who is rich:

> Poor person: pauper, mendicant, guttersnipe
>   Rich person: baron, magnate, tycoon, moneybags

In these examples, the words for a rich person are less formal than the ones for a poor person.  For a rich person, you can use these, if you're willing to use more than one word:

> person of means, person of substance (both formal), fat cat, deep pocket

On the other hand, in your comments you ask for adjectives that can be applied to a person.  Some of these are:

> Poor: impecunious, strapped, needy, unprosperous
>   Rich: wealthy, affluent, well-heeled/well-off/well-to-to, moneyed, prosperous

Comment: Which of the words you mention are matching pairs?

Comment: You can pretty much pick one from each list, although some are more formal than others and will therefore give different flavors of meaning.  I suggest that you look the words up in the dictionary and form your own ideas.  Once you have done that, feel free to share your ideas and get reactions.

Comment: None of "*impecunious, strapped, needy, unprosperous*" has the requested meaning of "*a person who has exactly enough for surviving, but not more*".

Comment: @VictorBazarov: I'm sorry, but I don't agree with you.  One of them has the precise meaning requested, two are very close, and one is a bit of a stretch.  I prefer not to explain my reasons for saying so, because I would like the OP to look up the words and draw his own conclusions.  But, feel free to refute my point of view if you should desire to do so.  Perhaps it will be instructive for all of us.